# Not able to display bootstrap table using map function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am new to react and working on a small app. I have a dummy service where there is a list of objects of movies. I want to display a table where I show the `title, genre, stock, rate`. Right now I keep on getting the following error and I am lost on what I am doing wrong. Any direction of help would be great

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movies from '../src/components/movies';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <main className="container">
        <Movies />
        </main>
      </div>
    
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Movies.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { getMovies } from "../services/fakeMovieService";

class Movies extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: getMovies(),
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.buildMovieTable()}</div>;
  }

  buildMovieTable = () => {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.movies.map((movie) => (
            <tr key={movie._id}>
              <td>{movie.title}</td>
              <td>{movie.genre}</td>
              <td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
              <td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };
}

export default Movies;
```

fakeMovieService.js

```
import * as genresAPI from "./fakeGenreService";

const movies = [
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
    title: "Die Hard",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471817",
    title: "Get Out",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 8,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471819",
    title: "Trip to Italy",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181a",
    title: "Airplane",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181b",
    title: "Wedding Crashers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181e",
    title: "Gone Girl",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 4.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd47181f",
    title: "The Sixth Sense",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471820", name: "Thriller" },
    numberInStock: 4,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  },
  {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471821",
    title: "The Avengers",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
  }
];

export function getMovies() {
  return movies;
}

export function getMovie(id) {
  return movies.find(m => m._id === id);
}

export function saveMovie(movie) {
  let movieInDb = movies.find(m => m._id === movie._id) || {};
  movieInDb.name = movie.name;
  movieInDb.genre = genresAPI.genres.find(g => g._id === movie.genreId);
  movieInDb.numberInStock = movie.numberInStock;
  movieInDb.dailyRentalRate = movie.dailyRentalRate;

  if (!movieInDb._id) {
    movieInDb._id = Date.now();
    movies.push(movieInDb);
  }

  return movieInDb;
}

export function deleteMovie(id) {
  let movieInDb = movies.find(m => m._id === id);
  movies.splice(movies.indexOf(movieInDb), 1);
  return movieInDb;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to render the "genre" cell for each movie with...

```
<td>{movie.genre}</td>
```

...but in your data, the value at `<SomeMovieInstance>.genre` is an object, not a string:

```json
{
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471819",
    title: "Trip to Italy",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471814", name: "Comedy" },
    numberInStock: 7,
    dailyRentalRate: 3.5
},
```

This it what is making React so angry; as the error message says:

> **Objects are not valid as a React child**

If you change that line to

```
<td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
```

...it should work.

Answer (score 2):

this error is for the `genre` object

change it to

```
 <td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
```

or the id of it:

```
<td>{movie.genre._id}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Faisal your answer is correct also. I will mark Alexander's as the correct since he beat you to it :)